Show that $\left \lVert \int_0^1 F(t) dt \right \rVert \leq \lVert F \rVert_{\infty}$ where $F=(f_1,...,f_n)$
Let $F:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function such that $F=(f_1,...,f_n)$ and let:
$$\int_0^1 F(t) dt := \left( \int_0^1 f_1(t) dt,...,\int_0^1 f_n(t) dt\right)$$
And:
$$\lVert F \rVert_{\infty} := \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \lVert F(t) \rVert$$
(Where $\lVert F(t) \rVert = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (f_i(t))^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ )
Show that:
$$\left \lVert \int_0^1 F(t) dt\right \rVert \leq \lVert F \rVert_{\infty}$$

My attempt
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \left \lVert \int_0^1 F(t) dt\right \rVert &= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \int_0^1 f_i(t) dt \right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
        & \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \int_0^1 f_i(t) dt \right| \\
        & \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^1 |f_i(t)| dt \\
        &= \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert f_i \lVert_1
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
And since $F$ is continuous each function $f_i$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ so by the Hölder inequality: $\lVert f_i \lVert_1 = \lVert f_i \cdot 1 \rVert_1 \leq \lVert 1 \rVert_1 \cdot \lVert f_i \rVert_{\infty}$, where $\lVert f_i \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f_i(t)|$. So we have:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \left \lVert \int_0^1 F(t) dt\right \rVert & \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert f_i \lVert_1 \\
        & \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert 1 \rVert_1 \cdot \lVert f_i \rVert_{\infty} \\
        & = \sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^1 1 dt \cdot \lVert f_i \rVert_{\infty} \\
        &= \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert f_i \rVert_{\infty}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
This was as far as I got. I don't know how to make $\lVert F \rVert_{\infty}$ appear. I would appreciate some help

For any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $$\left |\int\limits_0^1F(t),dt\right |\le \int\limits_0^1|F(t)|,dt\le |F|_\infty $$ where $F:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. The proof can be performed along the lines of the answer provided by @kobe using the dual space.

Let $u$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u\cdot \int_0^1 F(t)\, dt = \|\int_0^1 F(t)\, dt\|$. Then $\left\|\int_0^1 F(t)\, dt\right\| = \int_0^1 u\cdot F(t)\, dt$ is bounded by $\int_0^1 \|F(t)\|\, dt$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Since $\int_0^1 \|F(t)\|\, dt \le \|F\|_\infty$, the result follows.

You have:
\begin{align}
\left \| \int_a^b F(x)\mathrm dx\right\|^2&= \left \langle \int_a^b F(x)\mathrm dx,\int_a^b F(t)\mathrm dt \right \rangle=\int_a^b \left \langle \int_a^b F(x)\mathrm dx,F(t)\right \rangle \mathrm dt \\ &\overset{\text {C.S.}}{\le} \int_a^b \left \| \int_a^b F(x)\mathrm dx\right\| \|F(t)\|\mathrm dt = \left \| \int_a^b F(x)\mathrm dx\right\| \int_a^b \|F(x) \|\mathrm dx
\end{align}
Hence the triangle inequality holds:
$$\left \| \int_a^b F(x)\mathrm dx\right\|\le  \int_a^b \|F(x) \|\mathrm dx  $$
To conclude, note that $\|F(x)\|\le \| F\|_{\infty}$.
